# Failing to create a column and change its values in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I'm using a dataframe about movies that is somewhat structured like this:

```
movie_name      genres
    A       Comedy|Romance
    B       Action|Crime|Thriller
    C       Comedy|Musical|Western
```

I'm trying to create some kind of one hot encoding on the genres column by each individual genre
here's what i managed so far

```
# extract the unique genres from the genre column
gens <- str_split(movie_data$genres,'\\|', simplify = TRUE)
remove <- c('')                             # remove empty spaces that appear for some reason
gens <- gens[! gens %in% remove()]          # read above
gens <- unique(gens)                        # keep the unique genres

gens now like this
[1] "Comedy"  "Romance" "Action"  "Crime"  "Thriller"
[2] "Musical"  "Western"
```

So far so good, here is also what i managed to do with the one hot encoding

```
# this is specific for the Comedy Genre
movie_data$Is_Comedy <- integer(nrow(movie_data)) # create an empty column filled with values of 0

movie_data$Is_Comedy[which(grepl(gens[1],as.matrix(movie_data$genres)))] <- 1
 # turn all 0 values into 1 if the string "Comedy" is in the genres, gens[1] would be "Comedy" in this case
 # i turned the data into a matrix for faster execution
```

The code above works fine, but i am failing in trying to fit it in a loop of some kind for all the genres so i'm forced to write it once for each genre.
Here is the code i'm trying to figure out

```
for (x in seq(1, length(gens), by = 1)){
  movie_data[,gens[x]] <- integer(nrow(movie_data))
  movie_data[,gens[x]][which(grepl(gens[x],as.matrix(movie_data$gens)))] <- 1
}

prints out this:
Supplied 9000053 items to be assigned to 9000055 items of column 'Comedy'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

The error message is what i'm getting on my current data that i'm messing with, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `tidyverse` functions in this way to replicate a 0-1 variable style. You can separate at row levels and then assign a value of 1 for each row. After that using `pivot_wider()` can enable to obtain the structure with binary outcome for each genre:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% separate_rows(genres,sep='\\|') %>%
  mutate(val=1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = genres,values_from=val,values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  movie_name Comedy Romance Action Crime Thriller Musical Western
  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A               1       1      0     0        0       0       0
2 B               0       0      1     1        1       0       0
3 C               1       0      0     0        0       1       1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(movie_name = c("A", "B", "C"), genres = c("Comedy|Romance", 
"Action|Crime|Thriller", "Comedy|Musical|Western")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, this worked flawlessly, it did take a while to run on a big dataset but apart from that this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit` with `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df[1], mtabulate(strsplit(df$genres, "\\|")))
#   movie_name Action Comedy Crime Musical Romance Thriller Western
#1          A      0      1     0       0       1        0       0
#2          B      1      0     1       0       0        1       0
#3          C      0      1     0       1       0        0       1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(movie_name = c("A", "B", "C"), genres = c("Comedy|Romance", 
"Action|Crime|Thriller", "Comedy|Musical|Western")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```